# New to Django - showing detail object

Tags: python, django

in my Panel Folder I have the following
/Project/Panel/templates/posts/post_detail.html

I have created the class based view

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/panel/posts/1/ I get this error "no such table: panel_post"

I have also set the URLS

```
    path('panel/posts/', PostListView.as_view(), name='post-list'),
    path('panel/posts/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You should first `makemigrations` and `migrate` the database, you should also create a record with `1` as primary key.

Comment: I have already done that, the database and record is there

Comment: I don't understand this, I don't have a table panel_post !

Comment: Well there's your problem. Have you managed to solve it yet? Otherwise, maybe consider updating this question.